# Lubuntu 14.04 Software Updater behaviour

Tags: 13.10, upgrade

Will the Lubuntu Software Updater install Ubuntu on my PC?

I am wanting to upgrade to 14.04, but I am not sure if it will install Unity or Ubuntu-default packages.

I am running 64Bit 13.10 Lubuntu.

If the upgrade procedure does install Ubuntu-defaults and Unity, how can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and do

   `sudo do-release-upgrade`
2. Or by using Update Manager

   `sudo update-manager -d`
3. `sudo apt-get update` and `upgrade` is the command for software updating, not distribution upgrading. After these commands you should run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

It will upgrade to Lubuntu, not Ubuntu (or so it should).